# insert into OPENROWSET / SET IDENTITY_INSERT

Tags: sql-server

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;server=server;uid=ssa;pwd=xxx;database=eDemo;', 'Select ID,firstname,lastname,CNP,Phone, allowAmbSelection,Title,parafa  from n_staff ')
       SELECT id, 
              UPPER(firstname) firstname, 
              UPPER(lastname) lastname, 
              CNP, 
              Phone, 
              0 allowAmbSelection, 
              Title, 
              parafa
       FROM n_staff
       WHERE ID <> 1;
```

my problem is that Column ID is Identity and i would like to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT N_STAFF ON` for the insert table...i don't know how to do that..if possible...

Comment: Begs the question why you are using `OPENROWSET` to do this rather than linked servers. Issue #1 hard-coded password

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to SET IDENTITY_INSERT, you should use the "KEEPIDENTITY" table hint.

See [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

And see on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/keep-identity-values-when-bulk-importing-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) multiple examples on how to use the table hint.